# Usercontrol cant find the design data file?

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, xaml

I've got the following there it states it cant find my .xaml file:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.RectangleTest"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="130"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignData SampleData/RectangleSampleData.xaml}">
```

So it states it cant find RectangleSampleData.xaml, but if I take the url from the error box and paste in in my Run command it opens up the file, so what gives Visual Studio?

Comment: Does the file with sample data added to solution? Can you see it in Solution Explorer?

Comment: Yes, it was added in the solution explorer so i dont understand this